# Single class. TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
    def ProcessFailureSignatures(self, directory, report_dir):
        for element in os.listdir(directory):
        full_path = os.path.join(directory, element)
        m = re.match('(\d+)_FAILED_Pass(\d+)_(.+)', element)
        ......

def GatherTestResults(self):
    earliest =  time.time() - TEST_RESULTS_MAX_AGE_SECONDS

    for element in os.listdir(RESULTS_DIR_PATH):
        time_struct = time.strptime(element, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
        time_sse    = time.mktime(time_struct)

        outdir       = os.path.join(REPORT_DIR_PATH, self.accurev_info['Basis'], self.rtl, element)
        summary_file = os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR_PATH, element, "summary.txt")
        perf_file    = os.path.join(RESULTS_DIR_PATH, element, "performance_data.xml")

        if os.path.isfile(perf_file) and not self.IsTestComplete(perf_file, element):
           continue
        if(time_sse > earliest):
            if os.path.isfile(perf_file):
                self.ProcessTestPerformance(perf_file, element)

            if os.path.isfile(summary_file):
                self.ProcessTestSummary(summary_file, element)

            self.ProcessFailureSignatures(os.path(RESULTS_DIR_PATH, element), outdir)
        ...........
```

I get the following error, also when I type self.ProcessFailureSignatures in Python window, the function name doesn't appear. I don't understand why this wont be in the scope of the class. As it is written under class above the calling function.

```
File "fbe_test_analyze.py", line 621, in GatherTestResults
    self.ProcessFailureSignatures(os.path(RESULTS_DIR_PATH, element), outdir)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) is a module. You cant call it. Probably you want some function from the module. The list of functions is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

Answer (score 0):

use **os.path.join**

I will give you a example of returning the filepath of csv file

def symbol_to_path(symbol,base_dir="../"):

```
''' Reuturn csv path for a given ticker symbol'''

return os.path.join(base_dir,"{}.csv".format(str(symbol)))
```

symbol_to_path(symbol)